# Logic form not refreshing upon adding new product

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a problem with my form. You can see it here:

http://www.rawlinspaints.com/development/form2.html

Basically, the aim of the form was so that a user can choose a product and only receive the specific options for that product, which it does at the moment, however the problem is when the user clicks to add a new product, once they do that, the drop down no longer works to only show the necessary data for that product.

Can anyone help? Link above and code here, or alternatively if anyone has a better way of doing this that would be great, i'm aware the code is messy and i still have to sort it out so that the form data comes through in some sort of legible format!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#product").change(function () {
     var selected = $("#product option:selected").val();
     $('div').hide();
     $('#' + selected).show();

 });
 $('div').hide();
 });
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){


$(function () {
$('table').on('click', 'tr a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});

$("#addTableRow").click(function() {
    $("#mans").each(function () {
        var tds = '<tr>';
        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
            tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
        });
        tds += '</tr>';
        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
        } else {
            $(this).append(tds);
        }
    });
});
});


}//]]>  

</script>

</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="800" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" id="mans">
    <tr>
        <td>
         Product: <select id="product">
<option value="0">Select a Product</option>
<option value="1">Stair Nosing</option>
<option value="2">Stair Tread Covers</option>
<option value="3">Landing Covers</option>
<option value="4">Flat Plate</option>
<option value="5">50mm Convex Decking Strips</option>
<option value="6">100mm Convex Decking Strips</option>
<option value="7">Fixings</option>
</select>
<div id="1">
Quantity: <input name="Quantity" type="text" value=""></br>
Colour:
<select id="StairNosingColour">
<option value="Colour">Select a Colour</option>
<option value="1">Yellow</option>
<option value="2">Black</option>
<option value="3">White</option>
<option value="4">Luminous</option>
</select></br>
Size:
<select id="StairNosingSize">
<option value="Size">Select a Size</option>
<option value="1">750mm Length (L to R) x 55mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="2">1000mm Length (L to R) x 55mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="3">1500mm Length (L to R) x 55mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">2000mm Length (L to R) x 55mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">2500mm Length (L to R) x 55mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">3000mm Length (L to R) x 55mm Depth (going)</option>
</select></br>
Cutting & Drilling Instructions:
<input name="Cutting &amp; Drilling Instructions" type="text" value="Length/Pre Drilled Holes">
</div>
<div id="2">
Quantity: <input name="Quantity" type="text" value=""></br>
Colour:
<select id="StairTreadCoversColour">
<option value="Colour">Select a Colour</option>
<option value="1">Black with White Nosing</option>
<option value="2">Black with Yellow Nosing</option>
</select></br>
Size:
<select id="StairTreadCoversSize">
<option value="Size">Select a Size</option>
<option value="1">750mm Length (L to R) x 345mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="2">1000mm Length (L to R) x 345mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="3">1500mm Length (L to R) x 345mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">2000mm Length (L to R) x 345mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">2500mm Length (L to R) x 345mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">3000mm Length (L to R) x 345mm Depth (going)</option>
</select></br>
Cutting & Drilling Instructions:
<input name="Cutting &amp; Drilling Instructions" type="text" value="Length/Depth/Pre Drilled Holes">
</div>
<div id="3">
Quantity: <input name="Quantity" type="text" value=""></br>
Colour:
<select id="LandingCoversColour">
<option value="Colour">Select a Colour</option>
<option value="1">Black with Yellow Nosing</option>
</select></br>
Size:
<select id="LandingCoversSize">
<option value="Size">Select a Size</option>
<option value="1">1220mm Length (L to R) x 1220mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="2">2440mm Length (L to R) x 1220mm Depth (going)</option>
</select></br>
Cutting & Drilling Instructions:
<input name="Cutting &amp; Drilling Instructions" type="text" value="Length/Depth/Pre Drilled Holes">
</div>
<div id="4">
Quantity: <input name="Quantity" type="text" value=""></br>
Colour:
<select id="FlatPlateColour">
<option value="Colour">Select a Colour</option>
<option value="1">Black</option>
<option value="1">Yellow</option>
<option value="1">Beige</option>
<option value="1">Grey</option>
</select></br>
Size:
<select id="LandingCoversSize">
<option value="Size">Select a Size</option>
<option value="1">1220mm Length (L to R) x 1220mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="2">2000mm Length (L to R) x 1000mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="3">2440mm Length (L to R) x 1220mm Depth (going)</option>
</select></br>
Cutting & Drilling Instructions:
<input name="Cutting &amp; Drilling Instructions" type="text" value="Length/Depth/Pre Drilled Holes">
</div>
<div id="5">
Quantity: <input name="Quantity" type="text" value=""></br>
Colour:
<select id="50mmStripColour">
<option value="Colour">Select a Colour</option>
<option value="1">Black</option>
<option value="1">Yellow</option>
<option value="1">Beige</option>
</select></br>
Size:
<select id="50mmStripSize">
<option value="Size">Select a Size</option>
<option value="1">1000mm Length (L to R) x 50mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="2">1500mm Length (L to R) x 50mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="3">2000mm Length (L to R) x 50mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">3000mm Length (L to R) x 50mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="5">3600mm Length (L to R) x 50mm Depth (going)</option>
</select></br>
Cutting & Drilling Instructions:
<input name="Cutting &amp; Drilling Instructions" type="text" value="Length/Pre Drilled Holes">
</div>
<div id="6">
Quantity: <input name="Quantity" type="text" value=""></br>
Colour:
<select id="100mmStripColour">
<option value="Colour">Select a Colour</option>
<option value="1">Black</option>
<option value="1">Yellow</option>
<option value="1">Beige</option>
</select></br>
Size:
<select id="100mmStripSize">
<option value="Size">Select a Size</option>
<option value="1">1000mm Length (L to R) x 100mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="2">1500mm Length (L to R) x 100mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="3">2000mm Length (L to R) x 100mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">3000mm Length (L to R) x 100mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="5">3600mm Length (L to R) x 100mm Depth (going)</option>
</select></br>
Cutting & Drilling Instructions:
<input name="Cutting &amp; Drilling Instructions" type="text" value="Length/Pre Drilled     Holes">
</div>
<div id="7">
Quantity: <input name="Quantity" type="text" value=""></br>
Size:
<select id="FixingSize">
<option value="Size">Select a Size</option>
<option value="1">SureStep Clear Adhesive 310ml Cartridge</option>
<option value="2">Box of 100 Self Drilling Screws M4.8 x 25mm</option>
<option value="3">Box of 100 Wood Screws & Plugs M4.8 x 35mm</option>
<option value="4">Square Plate, Nut & Bolt 45 x 45mm M8 x 35mm</option>
</select>
</div>

        </td>
                    <td><a href="#">Remove Product</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<button type="button" id="addTableRow">Add Another Product</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, IDs must be unique on document context and you need to delegate event for new added elements

Comment: Thanks but i'm by no means a programmer, any pointers would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not binding the click event to the new element and ids need to be unique, they cannot be repeated.

Comment: Thanks but i'm by no means a programmer, any pointers would be massively appreciated!